# Php Session Object Interaction

Tags: php, oop, session, object

I ask you for advice.
I struggle with session/object interactions....

```
<?php
class ShoppingCart 
{

    public $products 

    public function __construct($session) {
        $this->products = $session['products']; 
    }

    public addProduct($id) {
        $this->products[] = new Product($id);
        $_SESSION['products'] = $this->products;
    }

}

session_start();
$shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart($_SESSION); 
$shoppingCart->addProduct(1);
?>
```

How would you write similar code? 
It's only the stub but I don't like my addProduct method and all this code in general. 
Please don't be critical and help me improve it. 
Maybe there are some design patterns or examples of such interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ShoppingCart {

    private $products = array();

    public function __construct() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
            $this->products = &$_SESSION['products']; 
        }
    }

    public addProduct($id) {
        $this->products[] = new Product($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it! It simplifies and removes my problem with object property/session divide. Thanks.